# Property 'validate' in type 'MappingService' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'IMappingService' typescript 2.8.0

Tags: typescript

i am using angularjs (1.5.8) framework with latest typescript (2.8.0) files. The below code is not compiled after updating to the latest typescript version.

The IMappingService interface:

```
export interface IMappingService {

/**
 * validation of the mapping of a T object from one type to another object type and return
 *  that new mapped object type
 * @param obj The object to validate
 * @param type The type of the object
 * @returns {T} The new validated and mapped object 
 */
validate<T>(obj: any, type: string, fields: string): T;    
}
```

The implementation of the interface:

```
export default class MappingService implements IMappingService {

    public validate<T>(obj: any, type: string, fields: string): T | T[] {
    let parsedFields = null;

    const replacedFields = fields.replace(/'/g, '"');
    parsedFields = JSON.parse(replacedFields);

    let tempobject = obj;

    if (obj instanceof Array) {
        tempobject = obj[0];
        if (!tempobject) {
            return [];
        }
    }
    ....
    return obj;
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 Property 'validate' in type 'MappingService' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'IMappingService'.
Type '<T>(obj: any, type: string, fields: string) => T | T[]' is not assignable to type '<T>(obj: any, type: string, fields: string) => T'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code does not work in 2.7 either. Not sure in what version of Typescript this worked but it should not really work as it is not type safe. Consider the following:

```
let m : IMappingService = new MappingService();
let r = m.validate<{ name: string }>({}, "", "");
r.name // I can access name, even though the type may be an array since MappingService returns T | T[]
```

You can either add an overload for arrays, or you can change the interface to the same signature as the implementation:

```
export default class MappingService implements IMappingService {

    public validate<T>(obj: any[], type: string, fields: string): T[]
    public validate<T>(obj: any, type: string, fields: string): T
    // Implementation signature
    public validate<T>(obj: any, type: string, fields: string): T | T[] { ... }
}

let m = new MappingService();
let r = m.validate<{ name: string }>({}, "", "");  // r will be an item 
var rr = m.validate<{ name: string }>([], "", ""); // rr will be an array
```

Comment: i have also a similar question after updating typescript version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49010496/type-ipromise-is-not-assignable-to-type-ipromisetemplatespagingmodel-t.
I would appreciate, if you can help me.